# How do I access my text files in the Resources folder using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

So in VB.NET I created a resource file called "source.txt" (as its a text file). My program will take in the text in the file, and then compile it into an executable.

How do I access this file which is in my resources folder in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `My.Resources`.  You will find the files in there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163972.aspx#S5